# Unity Scene Manager 2018

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried using

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadBScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("LoadSceneB");
    }

    public void LoadB(string SceneB)
    {
        Debug.Log("sceneName to load: " + SceneB);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneB);
    }
}
```

I have not been able to get the scene to change.
Anyone have any ideas?

**Please and thank you!**

Comment: Are you ever calling `LoadB`? Does the "sceneName to load: ..." message appear in the console? Are there any errors or warnings in the console or log? There's not nearly enough information in your question to identify the problem. Have a look at the examples here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the problem here is that you simply aren't calling the LoadB() method which means that SceneManager.LoadScene() is never reached. Inside the Start method just put

```
LoadB("InsertSceneNameHere")
```